# Get all data from rest api (odata) response with node recursively via @odata.nextLink

Tags: node.js, odata

I am getting an api response where 50000+ products are fed back at 100 at a time. At the end of the response, there is '@odata.nextLink'. Can one automate fetching the remaining data with node using the '@odata.nextLink'?

I have tried a while loop around the request but no success.

ie. while(body['@odata.nextLink']){ request... }

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something that looks like this:

```js
const fakeAPI = async id => (
  id==10
  ? { id }
  : { id, nextId: id+1 }
);

( async () => {
  let allResponses = [];
  let finished = false;
  let id = 0;
  while (!finished) {
    let response = await fakeAPI(id);
    finished = response.nextId===undefined;
    id = response.nextId;
    allResponses.push(response);
  }
  console.log(allResponses);
})()
```

Using [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) is pretty cool when looping with asynchronous code.

Comment: Thank you @ninofiliu, I will venture down this path.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote or accept the answer if it satisfies you ;)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```js
async function getAllResults() {
  var allResults = [];
  let url = 'https://your/endpoint/url/';
      
  do {
    const res = await axios.get(url)
    const data = await res.data.value;
    url = res.data['@odata.nextLink']
    allResults.push(...data);
  } while(url)

  return allResults;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "superagent" http library the following line works for me:

```
response.body['@odata.nextLink'])
```